# Python3.2 loops

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

```
# generate a random number between 1 and 99 sgenrand.randint(1,99) # your code goes here 
print("Enter coins that add up to 81 cents, one per line.") 
#promp the user to start entering coin values that add up to 81  
coin = (sgenrand.randint(1,99)) 
number1 = ("Enter first coin: ") 
sum = 0   
number1 = eval(input("Enter first coin: ")) 
while number1 != coin:   
    if number1 != coin: 
    number1 = eval(input("Enter next coin: "))
```

im stuck in this while loop. I want to have it that the user can hit enter without an answer and breaks out of the loop. after he breaks  out, the sum of numbers he previously added is calculated, and if the  sum isn't 81. tells the user he didn't reach target value, tells him  what value he reached and asks if he wants to start over!

Comment: Using `eval(input())` is considered *very* dangerous and is bad technique.  If this was suggested by the professor of this course, perhaps this isn't who you should be learning python from.

Comment: eval?   OK, slow down a bit here.  Your logic is ... confused.    You have flow control where `while number1 != coin` immediately followed in the true condition by `if number1 != coin` which by definition must be true.   Take a breath, search the web and stackoverflow a bit, then try again.

Comment: I was going to post an answer for how to make this work, but when I started really looking at the code, I realized I had no idea what was going on.  What is the point of the `randint` call?  Please edit the question to make it more clear what is going on.

Comment: @SethMMorton it was suggested by the professor of the course, what function should I be using in that case then ? 
randint is to generate a random number between 1,99

Comment: If you want an `int`, you should be using the `int` function.  You should ask you professor why `eval` is considered dangerous.  If they don't know, I doubt you will learn real python programming in that class.

Comment: I understand what `randint` does.  I want to know why it is in your code.  It doesn't seem to have any purpose.  I thought you were adding up to 81.  If you use `randint`, it certainly isn't guaranteed to be 81.

Comment: Feel free to send your professor these exact words, perhaps in a screenshot if you're worried about your prof thinking you're being a smart-aleck: **eval(input()) is dangerous and nobody does it that way**.

Comment: I was re-reading my comments and I realize I may have come across as a bit of a dick... sorry about that.  I was just trying to get to the bottom of what you were saying.

Comment: @SimonT its in the "introduction to programming using python" and its used a lot at the beginning of the book

Comment: @SethMMorton no worries, im trying to learn so im okay with whatever criticism people have to give me

Answer (score 0):

I like doing homework, I really do:

```
import random as sgenrand

def oneRound():
    target = sgenrand.randint(1, 99)
    print('Enter coins that add up to {} cents, one per line.'.format(target))
    total = int(input('Enter first coin: '))
    while True:
        s = input('Enter next coin: ')
        if not s: break
        total += int(s)
    if total == target:
        print('Well done.')
        return True
    print('You reached {}.'.format(total))
    return input('Do you want to start over? [y/*] ') != 'y'

while not oneRound(): pass
```

Comment: Oh, so the 81 was a red herring!  It was supposed to be the number returned from the `randint`